# Reading A Big File With Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read some files in a directory, which has 10 text files. With time, the number of files increases, and the total size as of now goes around 400MB.

File contents are in the format:

```
student_name:student_ID:date_of_join:anotherfield1:anotherfield2
```

In case of a match, I have to print out the whole line.  Here's what I've tried.

```
findvalue = "student_id" #this is users input alphanumeric
directory = "./RecordFolder"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(os.path.join(directory, filename)) as f:
        for line in f:
            if findvalue in line:
                print line
```

This works, but  it takes a lot of time. How can I reduce the run time?

Comment: If you read only sequentially you could use [memory mapped files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).

Comment: Define a lot of time :) In my case similar example takes about 0.392s on a 120M file. So should take about 1.2s on a 400M file. The only difference in your code and mine is that I'm explicitly opening file in 'r'ead-only mode.

Comment: no it takes around 5 min :/ for me

Comment: One little hint, totally unrelated to your question: `else:pass` is totally unnecessary, lose it. `if` statements aren't required to have an `else`.

Comment: Do you still have only 10 files totaling 400MB, or is it more than that?

Comment: ohh yess.. the else part. there is a print statement.. i just copy pasted from the raw file and typed as pass.... letme modify it :) The else part is required for the main file.

Comment: That's indeed ridiculously slow.. Check this out: http://pastebin.com/Z1qZMxDd What's your HDD and its read speed?

Comment: @favoretti. yes thats too slow.. HDD 500GB, 2MB RAM, i5 Processor

Comment: @MarkRansom as of now it 403MB, and this would increase with time.

Comment: @Whiskey, what I really want to know is how many files?

Comment: 10 files as of now..

@favoretti does OS makes a difference, I m in windows XP

Comment: @Whiskey well, OS might make a difference, but not THAT much difference. I/O load on your HDD will, however, make a difference :) It's quite hard to say what's causing that delay. Basically your file read speed is as fast as your HDD allows you to read it.

Comment: @favoretti so its not a problem with the coding structure .. :) it the OS and H/W env thats delaying it.. ryt?

Comment: @Whiskey that would be my safest bet without more information. As you saw in my paste example similar code traverses a 900M binary file in a bit under 4 seconds on an SSD powered machine. I do see a spike of 240MB/sec read during execution.

Comment: You could check how fast would be using `GNU grep` for this task. It is optimized to do exactly this task (looking for a line matching certain specification). If `grep` will be faster, we'll know that your code can be made faster. So try sth like: `grep -e '^[^:]*:studentIDyoulookfor:' RecordFolder/*`

Comment: Outputting to a file instead of to the screen (assuming stdout here is a tty) may also speed things up significantly. Terminals are very slow to print things, comparatively.

Comment: How often is `findvalue in line`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel how often? this is only to read and extract the matching line.

Comment: @Wooble You gave a superb idea.. I will try implementing the same and check and give an update :)

liori, i cant run the grep command, I am on Windows :)

Comment: @Whiskey You can get grep for windows (for free) .. I have it - unfortunately I don't remember where I got it, but it's out there.

Comment: google://grep+windows returns this as first hit: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

Comment: @liori Thanks, probably i wil go with the other approach, of setting up sqlite ..

Answer (score 4):

When textfiles become too slow, you need to start looking at databases.  One of the main purposes of databases is to intelligently handle IO from persistent data storage.

Depending on the needs of your application, [SQLite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) may be a good fit.  I suspect this is what you want, given that you don't seem to have a gargantuan data set.  From there, it's just a matter of making database API calls and allowing SQLite to handle the lookups -- it does so much better than you!

If (for some strange reason) you *really* don't want to use a database, then consider further breaking up your data into a tree, if at all possible.  For example, you could have a file for each letter of the alphabet in which you put student data.  This should cut down on looping time since you're reducing the number of students per file.  This is a quick hack, but I think you'll lose less hair if you go with a database.

Answer (score 1):

IO is notoriously slow compared to computation, and given that you are dealing with large files it's probably best deal with the files line by line. I don't see an obvious easy way to speed this up in Python.

Depending on how frequent your "hits" (i.e., `findvalue in line`) will be you may decide to write to a file so not to be possibly slowed down by console output, but if there will be relatively few items found, it wouldn't make much of a difference.

I think for Python there's nothing obvious and major you can do. You could always explore other tools (such as grep or databases ...) as alternative approaches.

PS: No need for the `else:pass` ..

Comment: @downvoter A downvote ***without*** explanation doesn't help *anyone* (OP, SO or me) .. I'm always happy to correct errors or improve an answer, but that requires *constructive feedback*, i.e., more than an anonymous click.

Comment: You haven't really answered any of OP's question.  You've just restated the problem.  Your edits certainly make the answer more productive though, so I am removing my downvote.