# How To Connect To Multiple sqlite3 Database with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

this is somewhat related to my earlier query..

[Reading A Big File With Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809925/reading-a-big-file-with-python)

The problem was with runtime, so i was suggested to use sqlite3 database, and it reduced the time to millisecond, and I am very happy, now the only problem i have is, connecting to different database files in the same folder. All the database files have the same tables.

The code I am using, reads only the first one, and doesnt seem to check the other databases.

The output is when the teacher, enters students ID, it is supposed to return the related records if found in the database table.

my Code is something like this, But I am sure I am doing something wrong, pardon me if its a silly one, as using sqlite3 for the first time.

```
#other codes above not related to this part
databases = []
directory = "./Databases"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    flname = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    databases.append(flname)

for database in databases:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
    conn.text_factory = str
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sqlqry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_1 WHERE std_ID='%s';" % (sudentID)
    try:
        c = cur.execute(sqlqry)
        data = c.fetchall()
        for i in data:
            print "[INFO] RECORD FOUND"
            print "[INFO] STUDENT ID: "+i[1]
            print "[INFO] STUDENT NAME: "+i[2]
            #and some other info
        conn.close()
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print "[INFO] "+e
```

Thanks For Any guides

Comment: I don't see how this code can possible work, it should generate a NameError on `sudentID`

Comment: @Daenyth There's a comment at the top of the code

Comment: Some aside comments: I would write 1) `databases = [os.path.join(directory, filename) for filename in os.listdir(directory)]`; 2) `with sqlite3.connect(database) as conn: ...`

Comment: How do you know it's not checking other files? Have you tried to add a diagnostic `print`? Like `print database` for instance. What's the output?

Comment: Lev yes i am printing the output.. it shows the value if the input ID is from the first database file, if i enter any ID from other database, it doesnt show the record.. though the records are there, i verify it with FireFox addon, SQLite manager

Comment: @Daenyth 

there is a statement to take the ID:
studentID = raw_input("#> Enter The ID: ")

Comment: What is your table structure, and how did you get the data from your 10 text files into your databases? (Also, why 10? Are they broken up by date or some other thing? You could maybe put them all in one table with an additional date field.) @LevLevitsky is suggesting to print the name of the database as you open it, to verify that you're getting what you think you're getting. Also do `print len(data)` to show how many records you are getting back. In general, people would be able to help you better if you post a single example that demonstrates the issue, and not omit possibly important code.

Comment: @Todd Actually I have not Missed out any codes related to the sqlite3 part.. when i print the database, it shows the names of the databases, I am testing the code now with 3 database files, and when iterating, it prints out the 3 database names. their names are db1.db, db2.db, db3.db

Comment: @Todd And I thought instead of updating the database, just to read any database files in the same folder, because, they will be created by various authorities of the school, just wanted to cut short... so that when they drop the database file in the folder, and make a query, the code should find out if a record exists with the ID in any database present in the folder :)

Comment: Why downvote him? As mentioned on his other thread, it doesn't help anyone unless you say why.

Comment: If i take out db1 and db3, and make a query with any ID present in the db2 file, it shows the record, the same query doesnt give a result when I put all the 3 database in the same folder. but inserting a print statements, shows all the 3 database names..

Comment: @Todd It doesnt hurt my ego, if i am being down voten.. I m here to seek help, downvoter, should mention the reason for voting down with a helpful answer, so that it helps.. :)

Comment: @Whiskey, the point is to provide a complete example that someone can copy out and run with the least effort. It should also be exactly what you're running so people see the same behavior.

Comment: @Todd Ok the thing, is as i mentioned this is a continuation, where previously i was working with text files.. I made a command line tool, and gave the people who were responsible for maintaing the Students records, they were using some other tool made in java which used to print to a text file, when i gave them this idea, they liked the concept.. hence i made a simple tool that converts all their text files to .db files...

Comment: Well put more print statements in to verify every assumption, and confirm what lines are being run and which aren't. That's the most basic way to see what's happening.

Comment: And probably they have started converting, but unfortunately I am stuck here now, because this is just to read the database records, believe this has no other sqlite section, other parts are useless to this post, like connecting to schools site, fetching some online results etc.. :)

Comment: ok Todd letme try inserting more print statements..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15016/discussion-between-todd-and-whiskey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Whiskey, sometimes it helps to try to break the problem down into a minimal example and see if that works or where it breaks. Since you are able to see the database names being printed as they are opened, my guess would be a problem with the query or possibly the data in the db even tho the records seem to be there. When you say it doesn't find the record you're looking for does it just print out nothing or does it print out the "[INFO]" line in your exception handler?

I put together the following minimal example, and it seems to be working as far as my understanding of your problem goes. My only other piece of advice to add to everyone else's would be to parametrize your query rather than using the raw input directly to make your app a little more secure. Hope it helps:

```
import os, sqlite3


"""
Create the test databases:

sqlite3 Databases/test_db1.db

sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo ( id INTEGER NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100), PRIMARY KEY (id) );
sqlite> 


sqlite3 Databases/test_db2.db
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo ( id INTEGER NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100), PRIMARY KEY (id) );
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2, 'world');

"""


databases = []
student_id = 2

directory = "./Databases"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    flname = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    databases.append(flname)

for database in databases:

    try:

        with sqlite3.connect(database) as conn:

            conn.text_factory = str
            cur = conn.cursor()
            sqlqry = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id=:1;"
            c = cur.execute(sqlqry, [student_id])

            for row in c.fetchall():
                print "-- found: %s=%s" % (row[0], row[1])

    except sqlite3.Error, err:
        print "[INFO] %s" % err
```

Comment: Awesome , million thanks, now it reads, it database files, cheers, you kinda saved my job..appreciated.. but i did not understnad still why my structure dint work, probably i wil look into it, after i get over this headache.. once again thanks..

Comment: Your actual code didn't work as we discovered in chat because you are ignoring several types of exceptions. If you log or print your exception messages, you will find the error.